# Does replacing Windows with Fedora still work in Windows 7 or do I need to do Dual Boot?

Tags: linux, fedora, windows

For the last 5 years, my procedure for setting up a Linux box has been to get the CDs (RH9, then FC11), boot the CD and just install Linux.  I do not wish to have dual boot; I want it to just run Linux.  Is this procedure still practical or does it no longer work?  I was planning to do this with Fedora 14 on a new Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process of installing Linux alone works as before. Just boot from the cd and make sure you select the appropriate option to use the entire disk for your Linux distro of choice. You definitely don't need to dual boot at all.